# Xcode free space requirement

Tags: xcode, disk-space, system-requirements

I am trying to update Xcode to 8.0. My OS is 10.11.6 El Capitan. However I am getting:

> **We could not complete your update**
>   There is not enough disk space available to install the product.

I have got 14.22 GB free space. How much do I need?

UPDATE: I do not know the exact figure, though I did manage to update with 17.21 GB free space later on.

Comment: I now have 20.89 GB, but I couldn't update Xcode.

Comment: Log out of App Store, reboot, log back into App Store, install.

Comment: I logged out, logged back in. I have 27 gb available still won't install.

Answer (score 21):

You'll need about 20GB free to do the install when you consider the space needed for holding/swapping files with the .dmg during the install process.

I saw this in the [Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/26973?answerId=90458022#90458022):

> Have a look at `About This Mac → Storage` tab.  You might see a purple
> segment labeled "Backups."  That's the local Time Machine cache, and
> it doesn't show up in the Finder's free space display because it can
> theoretically be purged if that space is needed.

**Update Sept 18, 2020**: Since this answer was written, Xcode free space requirements have been increasing.  As of Xcode 12, I needed at least 49GB of space to complete the installation.

Comment: Thanks. I have cleaned system and freed for 20 GB, and its updating xcode now .

Comment: It appears you don't need to clear out enough free space, the OP was able to get it work by some method not mentioned in either the question or the answer.

Comment: 20G is well beyond outrageous but yeah… Apple.

Comment: The Xcode app itself is roughly 10G. And I noticed that each user that has ever used Xcode has about 1G of files in the home directory. (NOTE: I didn't delete Xcode.app to get an easy 10G, but gave it some serious thought.

Comment: I have 66 GB free, but can't install Xcode 11 for this very reason... 

Comment: I have uninstalled android studio and it worked.

Comment: I have 45gb available still can install. I will try restarting etc.

Comment: @JoshuaDance My answer was written a few years ago. As Xcode advances, the free space requirement keeps increasing.  Yesterday, I couldn't install Xcode 12 until I had 49GB of free space.

Comment: Are you getting it from App Store or developer download @fsb ?

Comment: @bmike I got the last beta from developer site but the GM from App Store.  Do you think there's a diffference there I should call out?  I'm open to make changes as this answer is referenced quite often and I want to make sure it's correct.

Comment: I’ll probably drop a second answer and let you decide to change anything. Yours is good - shouldn’t matter in the end. App Store likely has to do he same double up as the download. Testing now on my non beta Mac

Comment: i have 24gb of free disk space. Still it keeps on giving same error

Comment: @MDThakkar Yes it will.  Did you see the update that Xcode 12 now requires over 40GB free?

Comment: @fsb Yes, after freeing 45 GB, it worked

Answer (score 5):

As of Sept 2020 Xcode now requires over 40 gbs of free space to install.

It finally started downloading for me today once I had 42gb of free space on my hard drive, as measured by the Get Info window. Cmd-I on your hard drive to open it.

Comment: Xcode 12 update is working for me with 37gb free

Comment: The new bar to cross with XCode 13.2.1, you need at least 45GB.