# 100GB+ of hidden space I can't delete or purge

Tags: disk-utility, install, catalina

I've tried everything... went into recovery tried repairing. Went into terminal tried to list any existing snapshots. Nothing... Am I going to have to do a clean wipe of the drive because of this Catalina disaster of a release...

[image]

Here's also a screenshot of About This Mac > Storage:

[image]

Comment: Do you use  > About this Mac > Storage > Manage… Store in iCloud? If so, your purgeable data is not all Time Machine snapshots. Also check the free space in Storage against that in Disk Utility > Free vs. Available & see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370809/85275 which has an explanation of how the purgeable data structure works [but isn't an answer to your question]

Comment: Edited with pic of Storage showing 166.81GB of Other. iCloud is fully setup and photos album only taking 800MB+ only that's full of video, photos from the past few years.

Comment: I wonder whether that's the system drive… is that DaisyDisk 4.8, or an older version? Try https://daisydiskapp.com/manual/4/en/Topics/HiddenSpace.html

Comment: Hang in there and let the spotlight index catch up. Have you left the Mac running overnight one night without sleep?

Comment: I'd try booting to Safe Boot Mode, which deletes lots of caches as part of it's operation.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on [modlin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373455/32815), when using [Ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu):

```
ncdu /
```

on macOS, you can avoid the [firmlink](https://www.swiftforensics.com/2019/10/macos-1015-volumes-firmlink-magic.html) problem by excluding `/System/Volumes/Data`:

```
ncdu --exclude /System/Volumes/Data -x /
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/download/latest/OmniDiskSweeper) which shows in a column-view:

[image: OmniDiskSweeper screenshot]

Largest folders will sort to the top.

I often will run it via

```
sudo /Applications/OmniDiskSweeper.app/Contents/MacOS/OmniDiskSweeper 2>/dev/null
```

Also: make sure that it gets “Full Disk Access” as shown here:

[image: Screenshot of Security & Privacy]

Answer (score 1):

Also try 'Boot Camp Assistant', click Continue and then wait.

You are just use it to trigger some cleanup action, not actually installing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

All commands are supposed to be run in a Terminal application.
In order to see where all this space is:

1. First, install Homewbrew:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. With Homebrew install ncdu:

   ```
   brew install ncdu
   ```
3. run ncdu:

   ```
   ncdu /
   ```
4. Actually, it's better to start with your home dir:

   ```
   ncdu ~/
   ```

Voila! You'll see where all your space is. You can repeat this step with directories at deeper level than root.
It may be required to run ncdu with `sudo ncdu` for some directories. Also keep in mind that macOS 10.15 Catalina system files are located on read-only partition.

Comment: I was absolutely going to recommend `ncdu` to crawl both the Data volume and the system volume. Super good tool, mind if I edit in usage for both?

Comment: @bmike On APFS & Catalina? Really? I don't get it to show the occupied space properly. Reason: firmlinks. ncdu doesn't take the firmlinks into account and re-iterates through this blackhole endlessly. After 4 minutes of scanning it counts 80 GB on my 64 GiB disk.

Comment: @klanomath Oh jeez, I was lucky where I started it. Yes firmlinks are going to be death to crawlers that cannot check filesystem boundaries potentially under any rock.

Comment: @modlin At least `ncdu /` won't work at all in Catalina because ncdu is not firmlink-ready. One firmlink is set at /System/Volumes/Data/ which "loopholes" to /System/Volumes/Data/System/Volumes/Data/ after the first iteration and /System/Volumes/Data/System/Volumes/Data/System/Volumes/Data/ after the second iteration... After ten minutes of scanning it counts 120 GB on my 64GiB disk. Additionally it won't detect snapshots.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open up a terminal window and enter
2. `cd /`
3. `sudo du -sk *`
   (Enter password when prompted)

In addition to printing out a bunch of “permission denied” error messages, that will print out how many 1k blocks each directory contains (although it will miss directories that start with .)

Assuming “bigdir” is a suspiciously big directory, cd into it and repeat:

1. `cd bigdir`
2. `sudo du -sk *`

Yesterday I found an old 50GB photo library backup in my Dropbox. Turning on Dropbox smart syncing fixed that.

Comment: This is a painfully slow and inefficient method compared with the GUI alternatives.