# Where does apple store interrupted update files?

Tags: xcode, sleep-wake, mac-appstore, storage

I started download of Xcode after cleaning out a lot of space on my MacBook(Guess you all know how frustrating it is to download Xcode without getting a 'Not enough space available' message). After deleting a lot of files, download of Xcode started, when the free space was around 25GB. But accidentally I kept my laptop into sleep mode and visited an hour later. I got a notification that Xcode download has been interrupted. Now when i try to download, it is saying 'Not enough space'. And when I check the free space, it is around 17GB. I am pretty sure at least 2GB has been downloaded. Will my MacBook store those files? If yes, where? If not, what was the difference between before and after going into sleep? Thanks for the help!

PS: Not much movement of files to add more space has happened in the mean time.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370806/app-store-not-enough-disk-space-to-install-xcode

Comment: @Tetsujin This is not what I was looking for. I want to know what was added between going to sleep and later. Initially:25GB free...after sleep and an interrupted update: 17GB. What may have happened between these events?

Comment: Did you check Disk Utility, for the purgeable figure & true 'free' figure?