# macOS Catalina can't be installed on Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, install

I'm currently running macOS Mojave (10.14.6) on a 2017 13-inch MacBook Air. I need to upgrade to Catalina to install MySQL.

So, I downloaded Catalina from the App Store but even after freeing up the required space, this dialog comes up... I don't know how to proceed from here.

[image]

Disk Utility:

[image]

Comment: We need to know precisely what Mac you have - from  Menu > About this Mac Model & year… & if the system won't let you inline the picture, send it to imgur.com & add a link in a comment. Someone can inline it for you.

Comment: @Tetsujin added it

Comment: Thanks - but can you do the same with the error message. [btw, it's likely to be 'Purgeable space' which you can see if you look at Disk Utility] See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370809/85275

Comment: What is the exact text of the dialog? Does it give any reason? How much space do you have free on the disk?

Comment: I removed the image of system information and just inserted the relevant portion in the body.  The equally critical info that we need now is the exact error message.  It would be helpful if you include a snapshot of your storage info so we can see how much is available.

Comment: @benwiggy There's no reason provided in the dialog box.

Comment: You could free up space by creating a bootable Catalina installer on a handy 8GB USB stick. Once the installer is created you can delete the installer from the Mac's hard drive, freeing more space. Macworld has a number of tutorials that can help you do just this.

Comment: 12Gb is barely enough free space for normal running. I'd suggest removing more space before the installer can work. I'd aim for at least 25Gb of free space at a minimum on a 128 Gb disk.