# What are ios simulator alternatives if I don't have 60 GB free space on my Mac?

Tags: xcode, big-sur, disk-space, xcode-simulator

I'm running a MacBook Pro (Big Sur OS) with the following disk space ...

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5s1  234G   15G   26G  36% /
```

According to this, [Xcode free space requirement](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252753/xcode-free-space-requirement), I would only be able to install the latest version of XCode if I had over 60 GB of free space.  I don't even have that much disk space on my machine and was wondering if there is a free alternative for my Mac where I could simulate running a web site on iOS.

Comment: How can you use 15G of a 234G disk and only have 26G left (use `df -h .` instead)? Also, which version of `df` is this, the Big Sur one gives a different output here.

Comment: And yes, this won't free up space. But there is no way around the 60 GB requirement so an easy option is to offload part of the 180-200 GB to an external disk.