# How much free space is needed to extract Xcode 13.3 .xip?

Tags: install, xcode, storage

With 37 GB free I'm still unable to extract the xip for Xcode 13.3. How much free space does it require to succeed?

The xip itself is 11 GB so that's obviously no indication.

The closest I could get to an answer was the comment about Xcode 13.2.1 to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/401518/40713) which says 45 GB needed to install, presumably using the AppStore though.

Comment: The top answer to QA you linked says it now needs 49GB.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, but others on stack overflow reported needing 60-80 GB for 13.3 so I don't want to exclude another jump

Comment: You need to check the figure in Disk Utility. 'Free' is not the same figure as 'Available', one includes purgeable data… which doesn't purge as nicely as you'd like. There's no doubt the free space requirement will ever-increase. Such is life.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok, thanks. On my system and system language "free" and "available" are used interchangeably though; the former by "about this computer" and the latter by Finder, with identical figures. Disk Utility shows only about a 100 MB discrepancy from those though, but in any case neither Disk Utility nor the realization that requirements increase will give me a concrete figure to aim for when freeing up space. The difference between 45 and 80 GB is quite large.

Comment: As has been shown many times on similar QAs, there's never a concrete figure for this type of requirement. Keep freeing up space until it works is really the only sure test. tbh, having so little free space on a drive is never a good idea anyway. It wears them out much faster than normal.

Comment: I would suggest that your disk is already too full as it is! Performance and even life can be affected by having very little free space on SSD.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, I've been worrying about wear leveling lately. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @benwiggy What percentage of free space would you prescribe per volume for decent wear leveling?

Comment: Call it 10-20% [it's a very rough guide] on a decent sized drive, more on a teeny drive. My qualification for 'decent' is at least 512GB, preferably 1TB or more. 256 is tiny & 128 is 'boot drive & nothing else at all'. A 128 you'd really need to keep half empty, which I'm aware is an issue for the myriad people who bought lappies with teeny drives just as they were at a prohibitive price, 5 - 8 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

About 50 GB free space enables extraction.